# How to filter nested array using map and filter with object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to return json data compare date Filter value. i am using Array.Filter and Map 
I tried below code its not working can you please explain how to get the return json compare particular date using filter Map

Array inside availabilities objects code compare to date i dont get the return value

I want to compare the date filter value

i added below my Code..

```
let cruiseFilterData = [{
      "name":"text--1",
      "availabilities":{
         "2019":{
            "year":"2019",
            "items":[
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"one"
                    },
                  "dateDepart":"12\/10\/2019"
                },
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"Two"
                  },
                  "dateDepart":"15\/12\/2019"
                }
            ]
         }
      },
      "sort":0,
      "featured":true
   },
   {
      "name":"text--2",
      "availabilities":{
         "2019":{
            "year":"2019",
            "items":[
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"one"
                    },
                  "dateDepart":"18\/05\/2019"
                },
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"two"
                  },
                  "dateDepart":"12\/10\/2019"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "sort":1,
      "featured":true
   },
   {
      "name":"text--3",
      "availabilities":{
         "2019":{
            "year":"2019",
            "items":[
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"one"
                  },
                  "dateDepart":"25\/05\/2019"
                },
               {
                  "discount":{
                     "name":"two"
                  },
                  "dateDepart":"12\/10\/2019"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "sort":2,
       "featured":true
   },
    {
      "name":"text--4",
      "availabilities":null,
      "sort":2,
       "featured":true
   }
]

let compareDate = 'Sat Oct 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Mauritius Standard Time)';

const linkedItinery = cruiseFilterData.map((element) => {
    element.availabilities = Object.keys(element.availabilities).filter((value, index) => {
        element.availabilities[value].items.filter((value, index) => {
            const dateValue = value.dateDepart;
            if (dateValue.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
                const dateSpilt = dateValue.split(' ')[0];
                const parts = dateSpilt.split('/');
                if (parts) {
                    const dateMerge = '' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0] + '/' + parts[2];
                    propDate = new Date(dateMerge);
                } else {
                    propDate = new Date(dateValue);
                }
            }
            if(propDate.toDateString() === compareDate.toDateString()) {
                return value;
            }
        });
        return value;
    });
    return element;
});

console.log(linkedItinery);
```

Comment: Bonzour Vivek and welcome to stackoverflow. Is possible to use `Date` Object instead of pure string ? Otherwise you will facing many trouble with timezone conversion.

Comment: Bonzour Yanis-git,
we could not modify json object its coming form client side..
Merci :)

Comment: iam not sure to get what you try to acheive so far, could you please show me what output you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure to have understand what you try to acheive so far, if your goal is to filter the list of available cruise base on the user date selection (represent here by your variable `compareDate`). You can update your code like following :

```js
    let cruiseFilterData = [{
          "name":"text--1",
          "availabilities":{
             "2019":{
                "year":"2019",
                "items":[
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"one"
                        },
                      "dateDepart":"12/10/2019"
                    },
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"Two"
                      },
                      "dateDepart":"15/12/2019"
                    }
                ]
             }
          },
          "sort":0,
          "featured":true
       },
       {
          "name":"text--2",
          "availabilities":{
             "2019":{
                "year":"2019",
                "items":[
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"one"
                        },
                      "dateDepart":"18/05/2019"
                    },
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"two"
                      },
                      "dateDepart":"12/10/2019"
                   }
                ]
             }
          },
          "sort":1,
          "featured":true
       },
       {
          "name":"text--3",
          "availabilities":{
             "2019":{
                "year":"2019",
                "items":[
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"one"
                      },
                      "dateDepart":"25/05/2019"
                    },
                   {
                      "discount":{
                         "name":"two"
                      },
                      "dateDepart":"12/10/2019"
                   }
                ]
             }
          },
          "sort":2,
           "featured":true
       },
        {
          "name":"text--4",
          "availabilities":null,
          "sort":2,
           "featured":true
       }
    ]
    
    let compareDate = new Date(2019, 12, 15); // Year, month, day.
    
    let linkedItinery = cruiseFilterData.filter((cruise) => {
        // Exclude all cruise without any availabilities
        if(!cruise.availabilities) return false;
        // check if current cruise have at least one availability for selected date.
        return Object.values(cruise.availabilities).findIndex(availability => {
           return availability.items.findIndex((item) => {
              // First we split the date by /.
              const [day, month, year] = item.dateDepart.split('/');
              // We craft date.
              const dateValue = new Date(year, month, day);
              // We compare both date to check if is the same.
              return dateValue.getTime() === compareDate.getTime();
           }) !== -1;
        }) !== -1; // -1 means not found. Is intersting to use findIndex here because he will stop the loop as soon as he find the first element which match with your callback critera. That avoid overlooping.
    });
    
    console.log(linkedItinery);
```

First i have change your `compareDate` but pure `Date` object.

then i filter original list by nested criteria. My goal is to find Cruiser which have availabilities, and inside this availabilities, check if at least one date match with the user input.

---

Please let me know if is not what you expect i will update my code according to your clarification.